# Density of ``$c_0$-like" functionals in dual Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional separable Banach space and let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an arbitrary infinite sequence of unit vectors whose span is dense in $X$ (but they do not necessarily form a basis). Say that a linear functional $f\in X^*$ is $c_0$-like, resp. $c_{00}$-like (with respect to $(x_n)_n$) if $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)=0$, resp. for all but finitely many $n$, $f(x_n)=0$.

Is the set of $c_0$-like, resp. $c_{00}$-like functionals $w^*$-dense in $X^*$? To avoid some easy counter-examples, let's say that $\inf_{i\neq j} \|x_i-x_j\|>0$.

I have neither a proof nor a counter-example.

Comment: The additional assumption is not necessary. With no loss of generality we may assume that the elements $x_n$ are linearly independent. Let $X_n={\rm span}\,\{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n\}.$ Then by the Riesz lemma there exists $y_n$ such that $y_n\in X_n,$ $\|y_n\|=1$ and ${\rm dist}(y_n,X_{n-1})\ge {1\over 2}.$ The functional $f$ is $c_{00}$ or $c_0$ with respect to $x_n$ if and only if it is such with respect to $y_n.$ Moreover $\|y_i-y_j\|\ge {1\over 2}$ for $i\neq j.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc This is not true. Without the assumption it could happen that there is a subsequence $(x_{k_n})_{k_n}$ say converging to $x_1$. Then a functional $f\in X^*$ satisfying $f(x_1)=1$ cannot be approximated by $c_0$ functionals.

Comment: I mean you can replace the system $x_n$ with another system $y_n$ for which the assumption is satisfies but $c_0$ and $c_{00}$ notions are equivalent.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I don't understand. We can let $(y_n)_n$ to be the standard basis of $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$, but we set $x_1=y_1$ and for $n\geq 2$ we set $x_n:=1/2 y_1+\sum_{2\leq i\leq n} \alpha^n_i y_i$ so that $x_n$ is some convex combination of $(y_i)_{i\leq n}$. Then $f\in c_0$ satisfying $f(y_1)=1$ and $f(y_i)=0$ for $i\geq 2$ is not $c_0$-like for $(x_n)_n$ although the spans of $(y_i)_{i\leq n}$ and $(x_i)_{i\leq n}$ coincide.